# why null values not return in when apply != in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I use this code

```
var items2 = from item in context.Images
             where item.Reported != true
             select item;
```

But not return null values in "Reported" column why?

Comment: Because null is not equal to true...

Comment: You should specify the type of item.Reported and which LINQ provider you're using.

Comment: I believe you need item.Reported.Value != true, if you allowed nulls in your schema then Reported is nullable. So you have a hasValue and value which actually accessing the entities true false value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`true` or `false` is not the same value as `null`.  If you need both to be returned then you will want to change your query to this:

```
var items2 = from item in context.Images
             where item.Reported != true || item.Reported == null
             select item;
```

Comment: it should be or instead of and.

Comment: It's a boolean operation, can you not just go `where !item.Reported` ?

Comment: In C#, `null != true` evaluates to `true`

Comment: @Moo-Juice if it's a `bool`, yes, but since it can be null, it's a `bool?`, so no, you cannot.

Answer (score 7):

Entity Framework, when translating your query to SQL, generates code similar to

```
select * from images
where reported <> true
```

Any operator in SQL used on null value returns false (`null <> true` too), thats why you do not get images with reported null values in your result set.

Comment: +1 SQL doesn't know `true`, so I guess it's translated to `reported <> 1`.  This does explain the behavior!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [`Object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) for the effect you expect, like so:

```
var items2 = from item in context.Images
    where !Equals(item.Reported, true)
    select item;
```

It should work like you've described, returning `false` and and `null` entries.

Comment: This would work if `item.Reported` is a value type, and fail spectacularly if it is not